# navigation button not working in java netbeans

Tags: java

i am creating simple crud system in java  form consists of 6 buttons Save,First,Next,previous,Last i attached the screen shot below of the form design.if click save button data successfully saved.and then if i click the first button first record is displayed and if i click last button last record should displyed successfully.if click next and previous button data is not working well.

[image]

Next Button Code is this

```
 String name = txtItem.getText();
       int qty = Integer.parseInt(txtQty.getText());
       int price = Integer.parseInt(txtPrice.getText());        
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
              con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/supers","root","");
              pst = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);                        
            String sql = "SELECT item,qty,price FROM stock";
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);

           if  (rs.next())
           {
             name = rs.getString("item");
             qty  = rs.getInt("qty");                                
             price  = rs.getInt("price");                                  
              txtItem.setText(name);
              txtQty.setText(String.valueOf(qty));
              txtPrice.setText(String.valueOf(price));                  
           }
           else
           {
               rs.previous();
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"end of the file");
           }


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(exmp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(exmp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: if  (rs.next()) is it correct

Comment: Does the data change so frequently that you actually need to query the database every time you want to display a different record? Can't you just load all the records upfront, put them in an array and use the first/next/prev/last buttons to travel through the array instead?

Comment: can you write the code easy to under stand sir please

Comment: Sorry, no, as it wouldn't be a proper answer (since it's not really a solution to your problem, just a suggestion) so I may get downvoted by others in the community. Also, the solution I would come up with will need to be integrated inside something I don't know the structure of, so you would need to rewrite it anyway.